# Algorithm to solve the system $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^k = k!c_k$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ efficiently

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods

$$ x_1 + x_2 + \cdots +x_n = c_1 $$
$$ \frac{x_1^2}{2} + \frac{x_2^2}{2} + \cdots +\frac{x_n^2}{2} = c_2 $$
$$ \vdots $$
$$ \frac{x_1^n}{n!} + \frac{x_2^n}{n!} + \cdots +\frac{x_n^n}{n!} = c_n $$

$c_1,\ldots,c_n$ are known constants. $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are the unknown variables to solve.

Comment: Cross-posted on cs.se: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33452/is-there-any-algorithm-can-solve-the-following-equations-efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Define the polynomial

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^ie_i(c_1,2!c_2\ldots,n!c_n)x^{n-i}$$

where $e_i(c_1,2!c_2\ldots,n!c_n)$ are the [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) then the roots  $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ of $f(x) = 0$ are the solution you are after. Thus this method recuces the problem to finding the roots of a polynomial (which numerically is fairly simple).

See for example [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/a-system-of-nonlinear-equations-power-sum.568099/) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86461/a-system-of-nonlinear-equations-power-sum) for more explanations (and other solution methods).

Comment: Thank you so much for your links! I will read them!

Comment: It's not clear that this method is numerically stable.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No and that is always an issue. One can easily think of cases where a naive implementation *will* fail, e.g. cases where we have solutions like $x_1=10^{10}$, $x_2=10^{-10},\ldots$.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, excuse me, why the roots of $f(x)$ give the solutions to the eqns in the question, i.e. $\sum_i^n x_i^k /k!= c_k,  k=1,2,\cdots, n$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you would consider "efficient," but you can use the first equation to solve for one of the variables. For example, $x_1 = c_1 - x_2 - \dots - x_n$. Then substitute this into the second equation to get $(c_1 - x_2 - \dots - x_n)^2 + x_2^2 + \dots x_n^2 = c_2$. Now you can solve for another variable, say $x_2$. Then plug the first two variables into the third equation, etc.

You have $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns, so this process should work, but I'd imagine it would take some time for large $n$.

Comment: There is one problem here. Solving for $x_2$ requires solving a quadratic equation, then solving for $x_3$ requires solving a cubic equation, and so on. But when we get up to $x_5$ there are no analytical solution (in radicals) to the quintic equation so I don't see how this would work.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: But for $n\leq 3$ then this would be the method of choice:)